# How to assign a string passed through a function to a structure member? C programming

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Okay so i am trying to pass an array of chars through a function, then assign that string of chars to the member of a structure for a binary search tree. my files are to be split up and i cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong.

this is my insert file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "struct_def.h"
#define MAXLEN 15

treeNode * insert(treeNode *nodeptr, char * tempWord){

  if(nodeptr == NULL){
   treeNode *newNode;
   newNode = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
   newNode -> s = *tempWord;
  }

}
```

And here is my struct_def.h file

```
#define MAXLEN 15

typedef struct treeNode{
  struct treeNode *right;
  struct treeNode *left;
  char s[MAXLEN+1] ;
}treeNode;
```

i keep getting errors like "insert.c:11:17: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[16]' from type 'char'"

please help i dont know if im just doing something fundamentally wrong or what. Thanks

Comment: "I" is capitalised in English.

Comment: Arrays aren't assignable. You have to use `strcpy` instead:

    `strcpy(newNode->s, tempWord)`

Comment: I know sorry! Today is not my day!

Comment: @0x499602D2: Why write the answer in a comment??? And why recommend a _dangerous_ function?

Comment: i just tried that actually... but it gave me some fatal error

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a dangerous guy. ;)

Comment: @0x499602D2 There's just a single capitalized _I_ in _"I'm"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Come again?

Comment: @0x499602D2 _"Come again?"_ Count is still one. Didn't help :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥε Good to know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not assignable and, by consequence, not implicitly copyable either.

Even if they were, `newNode -> s = *tempWord` tries to assign a single `char` to an array.

You will have to use `strncpy` (or `memcpy`) to copy over the array elements.

Comment: What do you mean by implicitly copyable?

Comment: @0x499602D2: "May be copied implicitly."

Answer (score 1):

The instruction

```
   newNode -> s = *tempWord;
```

Tries to assign to a an array `s` a char (dereferenced poitner `*tempWord`).

Change this to:

```
   strncpy (newNode -> s, tempWord, MAXLEN+1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this would help:

```
strncpy(newNode->s, tempWord, sizeof(newNode->s));
```

You can also use `strlcpy` if it is available on your platform.

Comment: In strncpy, length is the third argument.

Answer (score -2):

What you're probably thinking is that structures with string members are often declared like this:

```
typedef struct treeNode {
    struct treeNode *right, *left;
    char *s;
} treeNode;
```

In such a case, could assign to `s` a pointer value:

```
newNode->s = tempWord;
```

(note your original code even tried to dereference `tempWord`, which is a bad thing). This allows them to merely point to a string that is allocated somewhere else, thus saving memory.

But in your structure:

```
typedef struct treeNode{
  struct treeNode *right;
  struct treeNode *left;
  char s[MAXLEN+1] ;  
}treeNode;
```

The member `s` is an actual array of MAXLEN+1 bytes, it is not a pointer. So to assign to it, you have to copy the string, not just assign the pointer address:

```
strncpy(newNode->s, tempWord, MAXLEN+1);
```